# Trying to render markers with firebase into MapView Expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm using Expo and trying to render markers into a MapView using MapView.Markers. The MapView is rendering fine but the markers aren't showing up while I'm not getting any errors.

Screen where I'm trying to render the markers

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      jobs: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    const jobs = await firebase
      .database()
      .ref("jobs")
      .once("value");

    const jobsArray = snapshotToArray(jobs);

    this.setState({ jobs: jobsArray });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <MapView style={styles.mapStyle}>
            {this.state.isLoading
              ? null
              : this.state.jobs.map((item, index) => {
                  const coords = {
                    latitude: item.latitude,
                    longitude: item.longitude
                  };
                  return (
                    <MapView.Marker
                      key={index}
                      coordinate={coords}
                      title={item.jobtitle}
                      description={item.jobdesc}
                    />
                  );
                })}
          </MapView>
```

The code below is the code which puts the info from firebase into an array

```
export const snapshotToArray = snapshot => {
  let returnArr = [];

  snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
    let item = childSnapshot.val();
    item.key = childSnapshot.key;

    returnArr.push(item);
  });

  returnArr;
};
```

I'm still new to all of this, I would appreciate it A LOT if someone could help me find a solution!

Comment: Did you check your data?

Comment: This is what my data looks like for the jobs: https://pastebin.com/7VkQuhqt

Comment: I can't reach url.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8S5npiZ0 Could you try this one? this one should work